# Enviroment variables in docker containers - how does it work?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, environment-variables, containers

I can't understand some thing, namely as we know we can pass to `docker run` argument `-e SOME_VAR=13`.
Then each process launched (for example using `docker exec ping localhost -c $SOME_VAR=13`) can see this variable.

How does it work ? After all, enviroment are about bash, we don't launched bash. I can't understand it. Can you explain me how `-e` does work without shell ?

For example, let's look at following example:

```
[user@user~]$ sudo docker run -d -e XYZ=123 ubuntu sleep 10000
2543e7235fa9
[user@user~]$ sudo docker exec -it 2543e7235fa9 echo test
test
[user@user~]$ sudo docker exec -it 2543e7235fa9 echo $XYZ
<empty row>
```

Why did I get `<empty row>` instead of `123` ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your $XYZ is getting interpolated in the *host* shell environment, not your container.

```
$ export XYZ=456
$ docker run -d -e XYZ=123 ubuntu sleep 10000
$ docker exec -it $(docker ps -ql) echo $XYZ
$ 456
$ docker exec -it $(docker ps -ql) sh -c 'echo $XYZ'
$ 123
```

You have to quote it so it's passed through as a string literal to the container. Then it works fine.

Comment: So enviroment variable is passed via cgroup ? (In other words after running process in container (`run -e`) we can `exec` another process (which is not child of run process) and we can access to enviroment variables. Yeah?

Answer (score 0):

The environment is not specific to shells. Even ordinary processes have environments. They work the same for both shells and ordinary processes. This is because shells are ordinary processes.

When you do `SOMEVAR=13 someBinary` you define an environment variable called SOMEVAR for the new process, someBinary. You do this with `-e` in docker because you ask another process to start your process, the docker daemon.